# Components - set style width of component

Tags: ember.js

I can't figure out how to do some stuff with the components, ie:

This is an example of a working rendered progress bar from the dom:

```
<div class="progress-bar bg-color-teal" aria-valuetransitiongoal="25" aria-valuenow="25" style="width: 25%;">25%</div>
```

This is what I get in the dom, rendered from the component (never mind the values of attributes):

```
<div id="ember294" class="ember-view progress-bar bg-color-teal" aria-valuetransitiongoal="77" aria-valuenow="77" width="25">
    25%
</div>
```

Difference and problem: the style attribute that holds a width attribute.

And the component.js:

```
App.ProgBarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

    classNames: ['progress-bar', 'bg-color-teal'],
    attributeBindings: ['aria-valuetransitiongoal:aria-valuetransitiongoal', 'aria-valuenow:aria-valuenow', 'percent:width'],

    didInsertElement: function () {
        //$('#' + this.elementId).css('width', this.get('percent') + '%');
    }
});
```

But I cant bind the width in %, based on the percent attribute, to the style attribute.
Now, the didinsertelement hook works (I mean setting the width), but I want to do (and learn) how to do this with a normal approach - just like binding the aria-values and percent.

Setting the width to percent does not work - either because it is not in the style attribute, or because it is not in percent. How could I bind an attribute with the following logic (or similar):

```
 attributeBindings: ['someString:style'],
//someString: 'width:' + this.get('percent') + '%'
//someString: 'width:' + ['percent'] + '%'
//someString: 'width:' + percent + '%'
```

Neither of the commented lines work : the first one errors undefined is not a function (for get), the second one sets the width to "percent%", and the third one errors 'percent is not defined'...

The only workaround I could think of is using the routes model to return extra data, basically adding a new attribute:

```
styleString = 'width: ' + percent + '%';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempts to define `someString` didn’t work because they’re set when the component is defined, rather than at runtime. Change it to a computed property:

```
someString: function() {
  return "width: " + this.get('percent') + "%";
}.property('percent')
```

That defines `someString` as a property that depends on the value of `percent`. When `percent` changes, so does `someString`.

Comment: Works, thanks a bunch! 1 more question, im too tired to try it now - will changing the percent value automatically change the width? (I'm guessing that's what the property thingy does...

Comment: Yes, when `percent` updates, `someString` updates to include the new value.